# How does simple copy paste works in unix?

Tags: unix, theory, copy-paste

I wanted to know what happens when i right click on a file and copy it and paste it in unix.whats the theoretical concept behind it ?? when we say copy where the path of the file is stored ?? does it use buffers for that purpose?
Please provide me the basic concept of copy paste in unix.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste is handled by editor you use and not Unix.
So if you are using VI editor then its editors job to take care of it. Unix will come inot picture when you save the file.

Also you raised the point of copy pasting the file, this will be taken care by tool which you use to copy paste like WinScp. Again unix will come into picture once file is saved.